# Object of type PngImageFile is not JSON serializable

Tags: python-3.x, folium

I'm trying to do an image overlay. I'm using satellite data to study a phenomenon over Argentina, but I really wanted to use the interactive map through folium. So far, when creating an image, I'm getting an output. But, when I try to overlay the satellite image on to the base map, I'm getting an error message:

> Object of type PngImageFile is not JSON serializable

I don't have a clue of how to fix it.

```
from PIL import Image

fig.savefig('GS.png', transparent=True)

img = Image.open("GS.png")


import folium
from folium import plugins


m = folium.Map(location=[-31.416016, -64.188929],  tiles = 'Stamen Terrain')

folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(img,
                     [[ya.min(), xa.min()], [ya.max(), xa.max()]],
                     opacity=0.5).add_to(mapa)

mapa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for [`folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay`](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay), the `image` parameter must be a "*string, file or array-like object*":

> **image** (*string, file or array-like object*) – The data you want to draw
>   on the map. * If string, it will be written directly in the output
>   file. * If file, it’s content will be converted as embedded in the
>   output file. * If array-like, it will be converted to PNG base64
>   string and embedded in the output.

In your code, you passed a PIL `Image`.

```
img = Image.open("GS.png")
```

and an `Image` is not JSON serializable.

Try passing the path to the image file instead:

```
import os
img = os.path.abspath("GS.png")

folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(
                     img,
                     [[ya.min(), xa.min()], [ya.max(), xa.max()]],
                     opacity=0.5).add_to(mapa)
```

Or, if you really need the PIL `Image`, and since you already have numpy (because it's a dependency of folium), you can also convert the `Image` to a numpy array before passing to `ImageOverlay`:

```
img = Image.open("GS.png")

folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(
                     numpy.array(img),
                     [[ya.min(), xa.min()], [ya.max(), xa.max()]],
                     opacity=0.5).add_to(mapa)
```